# how to properly save an instant on a h2 database?

Tags: java, h2

I am using h2 and im new at it.

Currently I am trying to save an Instant object (I made it from an epoch with milliseconds) on my h2 table that is defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE transac (
  id   MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  time TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I also tried only with `TIMESTAMP` and got same results

but when I enter to the H2 administrator and see it (by doing a select) I see a value like this:

```
aced00057372000d6a6176612e74696d652e536572955d84ba1b2248b20c00007870770d02000000005a8ef8180000000078
```

with mysql it seems to work fine but with h2 is not, any idea how to properly convert it or send it?

Thanks.

Comment: What is an "instant?"

Comment: `but when I enter and see it I see a value like this:` where do you enter and where do you see it?

Comment: Hi @OldProgrammer and Tarwirdur Turor, Ive updated my question, please take a look